# OSL: How does Cycles implement derivatives?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, osl

The OSL language specification contains the following functions:

> float **Dx** (float a), **Dy** (float a), **Dz** (float a)
>  vector
>   **Dx** (point a), **Dy** (point a), **Dz** (point a)
>  vector **Dx** (vector a), **Dy** (vector a), **Dz** (vector a)
>  color **Dx**
>   (color a), **Dy** (color a), **Dz** (color a)

which:

> Compute an approximation to the partial derivatives of a with respect
>   to each of two principal directions, ∂a/∂x and ∂a/∂y. Depending on the
>   renderer implementation, those directions may be aligned to the image
>   plane, on the surface of the object, or something else.

Does anybody know if Cycles implements these functions, and if so, in which space?

Answer (score 0):

Cycles uses the same Dx and Dy funcions as OSL.